# What is the meaning of Adams words: "fall 12 feet into the kitchen"?

Tags: meaning

In Romance-Comedy movie *It's Complicated*, *Adam* (Architecture) discuss his building plan with Jane:

> Jane: I have an idea. What if we move my bedroom wall like 6 or 8 feet
>   that way, just so I can get more of the morning light? Not possible?
>
> Adam: Yes. But you'd wake up in the morning, walk out your bedroom
>   door and **fall 12 feet into the kitchen**.

Does it mean Kitchen is underground or what? How to understand Adam words about Kitchen room ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the kitchen is on the first (AmE) floor and her bedroom is on the second (AmE) floor, over the kitchen and the way the floor plan is laid out moving the bedroom wall (which has the bedroom door) will cause a gap which Jane would fall through.

The standard first floor ceiling height is 9 ft in the US.